# choose all except for "this" in jquery

Tags: jquery

i was able to hide rows matching a value like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name=select1]').change(function() {
        $("td").each(function(index, paragraph) {
            $td = $(paragraph);
            if ($td.html() === $('select[name=select1]').val()) {
                //hide the matched row rather than remove it
                $(not(this)).parent("tr:first").hide();
            }
        });
        $('select[name="select1"]').on('change', function() {
            $("tr").show();
        });
    });
});
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You have nested two `change` event handlers for starters. That is never a good idea. Please show an example of your HTML to put the code in perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know your html markup but just hide all elements and "unhide" the one you don't want to hide.

```
if ($td.html() === $('select[name=select1]').val()) {
    //hide the matched row rather than remove it
    $('tr').hide();
    $(this).parent("tr:first").show();
}
```